# How to host CouchDb in Heroku

Tags: heroku, couchdb-2.0

I have a node.js application that is using Apache CouchDB for it's NoSQL database. I am new to Heroku and just deployed my API to Heroku instance. I tried pusing docker image of Couchdb to heroku but its throwing error

[WARN  tini (3)] Tini is not running as PID 1 and isn't registered as a child subreaper.
Zombie processes will not be re-parented to Tini, so zombie reaping won't work.
To fix the problem, use the -s option or set the environment variable TINI_SUBREAPER to register Tini as a child subreaper, or run Tini as PID 1.
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 62: exec: console: not found

Can someone help provide me with some instructions on how I can host couchdb on heroku?